# How do I put my JavaScript code on a url so that anyone can link in their HTML files?

Tags: javascript, html

Apologies if my terms are wrong, I am relatively new to programming.

My doubt is that I want my code to be available online on a link like bootstrap, but do not know how to do that.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks/

Comment: You can publish your code in GitHub and use any CDNs like jsDelivr to share the code.

Comment: Github, Pastebin, Unpkg are some options

Answer (score 2):

You can create a package of your javascript code and host it on [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-scoped-public-packages). Since you want it to be linked easily through HTML like bootstrap, [UNPKG](https://unpkg.com/) can link any npm package. Hope this gives you a good direction to follow.